# How to handle word wrap in iOS' UILabel/UITextView for the Chinese language for multiple screen sizes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, localization, nslinguistictagger

I've an app that is being localized to Simplified `Chinese`. I've noticed that sometimes `UILabels` and `UITextViews` wrap characters but not entire words.

It seems a bit crazy to go through the `Chinese` language to manually point out line breaks for every single localized string for every single device size and orientation.

Is there a way to use `NSLinguisticTagger` to extract the words and tell `UILabel` to wrap based on what was tagged?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

TextView.sizeToFit()
```

Same for labels. It works for me not in Chinese but you can try

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Chinese. Just had someone review our app and they said it's wrapping by character.

Comment: Wrapping by words really just means wrapping on space characters. There are no space characters in Chinese or Japanese. To wrap Chinese or Japanese by _words_ would require the OS to have semantic and/or syntactical knowledge of your Chinese text. It just doesn't have that, so it can't do it. Compare this to most other languages (incl. Korean, for example): words are easily recognizable because they are separated by space characters.